# brick breaker hit test error

Tags: actionscript-3, hittest

okay heres the thing, Im making a brick breaker game. im trying to build it so that i can add the bricks on the stage by hand instead of using a code.

on the stage a have a ball ("Ball") that for the moment is folowing the mouse movement, and a brick movieclip with a hit test code inside.

heres the mainframe code:

```
import flash.events.Event;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveBall);

function moveBall (e:Event):void{
Ball.x = mouseX;
Ball.y = mouseY;
}
```

and heres the code that i wrote inside the brick movieclip:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,checkHit);

function checkHit (e:Event):void{
    if(this.hitTestObject(Ball)){
    trace ("HIT!!");
}
}
```

thats all the code and the ball and brick are alredy on the stage. 
when i ran this i get "Symbol 'brick', Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 6 1120: Access of undefined property Ball."

line 6 is:

```
if(this.hitTestObject(Ball)){
```

please tell me why and how to fix this.. i tried to change the object to stage.Ball and I still get an error :(

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive the error because `Ball` is not in the scope of any of your bricks (it's a different timeline that doesn't know about Ball).

you could access the Ball by using the `parent` keyword.  eg: `MovieClip(parent).Ball` would probably work.

A suggestion that would be more efficient:
change this `addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveBall);` to use `MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE` instead of ENTER_FRAME. That way it only fires if the mouse is moving.

Comment: thanks for the help! the MOUSE_MOVE will be used =] though i tried changing the line to if(this.hitTestObject(MovieClip.parent(Ball))){ and i get the same error again plus "Call to a possibly undefined method parent through a reference with static type Class." and if i write "Ball.parent.Ball" the old error jumps anyway. =/

Comment: Should be:  `if(this.hitTestObject(MovieClip(parent).Ball)){`